# Unable to import another file from same workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual studio code. Currently facing a problem as shown below whereby there is an error and I am unable to import my code from the same workspace (but another folder). Although I am fairly new to python as well, I am quite certain that the code i used is correct.

```
from business.request_process import *
```

Would greatly appreciate if anyone know what happens to be the problem as well as how to fix it. Thanks!

[photo of my workspace + code + error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwWTJ.png)

Comment: try `Practical5.business.request_process import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `request_io.py` is in directory `presentation`, and there is no directory named "business" in there.

You can append any directory you want to import in the system path, your code should be like this

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_your_workspace/Practical5/business')
from request_process import *
```

Or move `request_io.py` to where it can see `business` (Practical5 in this case)